# How to select a value from a drop down list and automatically populate another field

Tags: reporting-services

I have to build a report in which I have to display a quality document filename and revision.  The user running the report has to select which document was used at production.  The design of the report is set up to show the file name in one field and the revision in a separate field.  How do I set up a drop-down list and/or parameter that will allow the user to select a document from the list, but will also update the revision field?  I have a dataset where I queried the document file name and revision, but the parameter setup only allows me to select one field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need two parameters and two dataset - one parameter for the filename and the second for the Revision.

You'll need a second dataset for the Revision parameter which filters the data based on the Filename parameter. This will generate a list of Revisions for the Filename  the users selects.

```
SELECT Revision 
FROM TABLE
WHERE FILENAME = @FILENAME
```

Then your main data query would use both the Filename and Revision.

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE FILENAME = @FILENAME
AND REVISION = @REVISION
```

If I misunderstood and you don't need separate parameters because there's only one Revision per Filename, then you'd want to combine the data from the two columns into 1 for the the Parameter Label and just have File Name as the Value.

```
SELECT FILENAME, FILENAME + ' - ' + Revision as FILE_LABEL
FROM TABLE
```

Then for the Filename parameter, change the label to use FILE_LABEL.